# Prioritized socket communication

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a client-server communication between a mobile and a PC(server). 
In the communication I have four sockets: two of these are to send and receive data, and the other two are for some kind of keep-alive, since I need to detect disconnections as fast as I can.

As long as the connection is OK, the data will travel without any problem. But I want to establish some priority in order to be sure that the keep alive (remember: two sockets) channel is always sending data, unless the connection between server-client is dead.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Since the network line is shared you will hit some chock point. Have you thought about threading and thread priority to help increase the frequency of the heart beat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would question your setup with four sockets.

First, having separate connection for discovering when remote end dies does not give you any advantage, but in fact introduces a race condition when that "keep-alive" connection goes down but "data" connection is still intact. Implement periodic heartbeats over same data connection when there's no activity.

Then two independent data connections between same nodes compete for bandwidth. Network stacks usually don't optimize across connection boundaries, so you get twice TCP overhead for no gain. Implement data exchange over the same TCP connection - you'll get better throughput (maybe at the expense of small latency increase, but only good measurement would tell that).

Last, but not least, four connections require four listening TCP ports, thus potentially four holes in a firewall somewhere. Reduce that to a single port, and administrator of that firewall will forever be your friend.

Answer (score 0):

When using TCP for transmission your TCP protocol stack will inform you whenever you try to send data and the (TCP) connection is broken. If you control both server and client code you may well implement your heartbeat in between your data transmission over TCP.

If TCP's connection failure detection on the respective devices is too slow for your purpose you can implement some single packet ping-pong scheme between client and server, like the "SNMP echo request" a.k.a. "ping" - or if SNMP is not an option, maybe sending UDP packets back and forth will do the trick.

In any case you will need some kind of timeout mechanism (which is already implemented in the TCP stack), which implies that the detection of a broken connection will be delayed with the delay time bounded by the timeout duration.